# How can I have auto fill functionality as default in my custom codes?

Tags: swift, swiftui

As you know we can just type **Button(** in SwiftUI and chose (action:label) on options and press Enter key, then Xcode make us a ready default code for start editing, it would be like this:

```
Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Button") })
```

I want same functionality in my code, therefore I just tried to re-create Button, but I do not know how could I possibly make it happen, I am getting this code after pressing Enter as default, which missing `{}` for **action** and `{ Text("Button") }` for **label**:

```
CustomButton(action: () -> Void, label: () -> _)
```

**My Goal:** Which I would like get **autofilled default** like this:

```
CustomButton(action: {}, label: { Text("CustomButton") })
```

How could I make it possible? also I know about **code Snippet**, I do not want use that, I like my codes have default value from start, for editing them.

**my used code:**

```
struct CustomButton<Content: View>: View {
    
    var action: () -> Void
    var label: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return label()
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .onTapGesture { action() }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use code snippets? That sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: about Auto fill default, think about this that I am going send you **CustomButton** code and I like you could make does auto fill by default without using your code snippet, that would be so cool and handy to use for you, right?

Comment: Seeing how this feature is only available in a proper Xcode project, and not in Playgrounds, and it's not available on AppCode either, I don't think there's something in the Swift code of `Button` that is telling Xcode to show those defaults (even if there is, it's not public API). This is probably Xcode's own implementation details.

Comment: You know there is no big issue to make them Snippet, but do you know how many custom code I got? if I Snippet all, then I would sinking in a sea of Snippet! then i thought what if we could give all this as default, and make it more easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said you didn't want to use code snippets, but I think that's the only way. You *can* get very close to the default behavior though. The trick is to use `/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/` and `/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/`. These tell Xcode that everything between them should be autofilled.

So I assume you want something like this?

| Original Xcode `Button` | Custom `Button` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Button pre-filled with default text] | [image: Button pre-filled with custom label text] |

First, let's see what Xcode does for a normal Button. Type in **Button(**, then **copy** what Xcode autofills into a text editor:

```
Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
    /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Text("Button")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
})
```

As you can see, there are `/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/` and `/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/` surrounding the autofill text. You can customize this to your need, like this:

```
Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
    /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Text("CustomButton")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
})
```

Try pasting this back into Xcode. It will look just as expected!

[image: Button pre-filled with custom label text]

---

Now you can make this into a code snippet. Highlight the button text, right click, then click <kbd>Create Code Snippet</kbd>.

[image: Click Create Code Snippet in the popup]

Then, enter something into the `Completion` field. This will be what Xcode will replace with your autofilled button code.

[image: Enter "CustomButton" in the Completion text field]

Finally, you can use it!

| 1. Type `CustomBut` | 2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Typing "CustomBut", and Xcode pops up with a suggestion to use that code snippet] | [image: "CustomBut" is replaced with the autofilled code snippet!] |

Comment: thanks a lot for your complete explaining, that is just great, I was wandering if we could bake that auto fill default inside our codes, and help us and prevent  us going to make it from code snippet! my all goal is not using snippet at first place, so if it is not possible, then your answer is best possible right now for use.

Comment: @swiftPunk yeah I think it's not possible. But if someone else finds a way, you can always unaccept my answer.

Comment: I think it is not possible because **Sweeper** said so, and I think he knows better, with that said your answer is best for us to use right now, thanks a lot.